# Get Sum Of All Transactions Per Month Including Months With No Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

To simplify table structure, I am going to use a simple table sample. Supposing I have this table:

```
+------+------------+-------------+
| id   | date       | Quantity    |
+------+------------+-------------+
|    1 | 2014-01-01 |          10 |
|    2 | 2014-01-20 |          20 |
|    3 | 2014-02-03 |          30 |
|    4 | 2014-02-28 |          40 |
|    5 | 2014-06-01 |          50 |
|    6 | 2014-06-13 |          24 |
|    7 | 2014-12-12 |          45 |
|    8 | 2014-12-18 |          10 |
+------+------------+-------------+
```

I need to get the sum of `Quantity` per month including months with no transaction

I have tried this, but it only displays months with transactions.

```
Select Month(date), Sum(Quantity) from tablename Group By Month(date)
```

Do not mind the year. Lets just say the table only contains current year data

Comment: Year does matter. Do you have only one year's data?

Comment: I know that. Thats why i said "Lets just say"

Answer (score 2):

Create a dummy table storing the months:

```
Select months.m, isnull(Sum(Quantity),0) as Q 
from tablename right join 
(VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) 
AS months(m)
on months.m=Month(tablename.date)
Group By months.m
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d372f/9)

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea. The key is to create a table listing the months you need and then attach the real data with an outer join.

```
with months(mon) as (
    select  1 union all select  2 union all select  3 union all
    select  4 union all select  5 union all select  6 union all
    select  7 union all select  8 union all select  9 union all
    select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
)
select m.mon, coalesce(sum(quantity), 0) as quantity
from months m left outer join <T> t on month(t.date) = m.mon
group by m.mon
```

There are lots of ways to create the list of months if you need more than a year of data from January to December or don't like this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Months as
(
  SELECT 1 AS MNTH
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MNTH+1 FROM Months WHERE MNTH<12
)

SELECT MONTH(MNTH),SUM(QUANTITY) 
FROM Months M LEFT JOIN TABLENAME T ON M.MNTH = MONTH(T.DATE)
GROUP BY MONTH(MNTH)
```

Comment: You don't want to group by the column on the right side of the join since it can be null.